# Options of the first question returning on every question in this laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Options of the first question returning on every question in this laravel query.

```
$questions = Question::with('option')
                ->join('categories', function($join) use ($category) {
                    $join->on('categories.id','=','questions.category_id');
                    $join->where('categories.title', '=', $category);
                })
                ->inRandomOrder(5)->get();
```

the question class.

```
public function option()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
}
```

the option class.

```
public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
    }
```

Comment: because you are requesting it using `with('option')`?

Comment: show relation code of Question model.

Comment: public function option()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query selects all columns: `select * from questions join categories ...`

As a result, the `categories` columns override the `questions` columns with the same name.

You have to limit the selected columns:

```
$questions = Question::with('option')
    ->join('categories', function($join) use ($category) {
        $join->on('categories.id','=','questions.category_id');
        $join->where('categories.title', '=', $category);
    })
    ->inRandomOrder(5)
    ->get(['questions.*']);
```

Or use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$questions = Question::with('option')
    ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use($category) {
        $query->where('title', '=', $category);
    })
    ->inRandomOrder(5)
    ->get();
```